# Nginx/Apache2 WebSocket connection to failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, nginx, django-channels

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, Django 2.1, Python 3.6, Nginx, Gunicorn and the testing project I copied from is through this link: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_1.html

I deployed the ubuntu server based on the instructions here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04#troubleshooting-nginx-and-gunicorn

But i got the 404 error. 
    WebSocket connection to 'ws://54.184.201.27/ws/chat/lobby/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404 Chat socket closed unexpectedly

I got some idea from the github issues posted here: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1942 and answers are that I should add some code to my conf file. But I still got the error.

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/project.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 54.184.201.27;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /var/www/django-channels/static;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;


    }

}
```

After I add the proxy_set_header Host $host, I got the error:

```
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '54.184.201.27,54.184.201.27'. The domain name provided is not valid according to RFC 1034/1035.
```

I didn't put the proxy_set_header Host $host here as it will gave the error of wrong ip address. Any idea of how to solve the problem?

It seems like since i used gunicorn, i should not put those proxy setting which might be duplicated.

Comment: According to the link you provided you're missing `proxy_set_header Host $host;` in the config

Comment: After I added that, i got the error: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '35.162.166.243,35.162.166.243'. The domain name provided is not valid according to RFC 1034/1035.

Comment: The `server_name` has to be in the form of a domain name, not IP address. Check out this page in the docs https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Comment: what if i don't have a domain. shall i just use 'localhost' instead? or simply delete that?

Comment: You can use `server_name "";` if you don't have a domain

Comment: However, it i don't put the ip address to the server_name, when i enter the ip address to the url, it redirect to the default nginx page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186319/discussion-between-fancylynn-and-ken4scholars).